# Kotlin Converted Activity code to fragment doesn't work

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, textview

I'm trying to convert my activity code to a fragment so I can make a tab layout.
Now when I copied the code from my activity to the fragment I got some errors. I tried to solve them but now my code doesn't work.

What should happen is that when I tap the textview it should flip and show a random text. In the Activity it works fine but now I tried converting it to a fragment it doesn't work. Nothing happens when I tap the textview.

Even when I remove the animation, and only use the textview the random texts won't appear when clicked in it. It seams like the setOnClickListener doesn't work.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

This is my fragment code:

```
import android.animation.AnimatorInflater
import android.animation.AnimatorSet
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
//import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.TabStartKaartFragment.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_tab_start_kaart.*

class TabStartKaartFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var front_anim: AnimatorSet
    lateinit var back_anim: AnimatorSet
    var isFront = false

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_start_kaart, container, false)

        val scale = getActivity()?.applicationContext?.resources?.displayMetrics?.density
        tvstartkaart.cameraDistance = 8000 * scale!!
        tvstartkaartachterkant.cameraDistance = 8000 * scale
        front_anim = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.anim.font_animation) as AnimatorSet
        back_anim = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.anim.back_animation) as AnimatorSet



        val Carts = arrayOf("" +
                "Bunch of random texts",

            )



        tvstartkaart.setOnClickListener() {

            if (isFront) {

                front_anim.setTarget(tvstartkaart)
                back_anim.setTarget(tvstartkaartachterkant)
                front_anim.start()
                back_anim.start()
                isFront = false
            } else {

                val random = Carts.random()
                tvstartkaart.setText(random)

                front_anim.setTarget(tvstartkaartachterkant)
                back_anim.setTarget(tvstartkaart)
                front_anim.start()
                back_anim.start()
                isFront = true
            }

        };
    }
```

This is my original activity code:

```
import android.animation.AnimatorInflater
import android.animation.AnimatorSet
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlin.random.Random

class StartKaartActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var front_anim:AnimatorSet
    lateinit var back_anim:AnimatorSet
    var isFront = false

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_kaart)

        //Set Backbutton Bar & Logo
        val display = supportActionBar
        display?.title = ""
        //display?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        display?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.backarrow)
        //display?.setLogo(R.drawable.logo)
        display?.setIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        display?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


        val scale = applicationContext.resources.displayMetrics.density
        val tvstartkaart = findViewById<TextView>(com.fotf.klimaatambitiegame.R.id.tvstartkaart)
        val tvstartkaartachterkant = findViewById<TextView>(com.fotf.klimaatambitiegame.R.id.tvstartkaartachterkant)
        tvstartkaart.cameraDistance = 8000 * scale
        tvstartkaartachterkant.cameraDistance = 8000 * scale
        front_anim = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(applicationContext, R.anim.font_animation) as AnimatorSet
        back_anim = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(applicationContext, R.anim.back_animation) as AnimatorSet



        val Carts = arrayOf("" +
                 "Bunch of random texts",

            )



        tvstartkaart.setOnClickListener() {

            if (isFront) {

                front_anim.setTarget(tvstartkaart)
                back_anim.setTarget(tvstartkaartachterkant)
                front_anim.start()
                back_anim.start()
                isFront = false
            } else {

                val random = Carts.random()
                tvstartkaart.setText(random)

                front_anim.setTarget(tvstartkaartachterkant)
                back_anim.setTarget(tvstartkaart)
                front_anim.start()
                back_anim.start()
                isFront = true
            }

        };
    }
}
```

This is my xml fragment file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/achtergrondnowhite"
    tools:context=".TabStartKaartFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="372dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        android:text="Klik op de kaart om een nieuwe kaart te krijgen. \n\nGeef het goede antwoord op de vraag en verdien een houder."
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.487"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvstartkaart"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:background="@drawable/kaartstartvoorkant"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.508" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvstartkaartachterkant"
        android:layout_width="353dp"
        android:layout_height="453dp"
        android:background="@drawable/kaartstartachterkant"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My front animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="180"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:duration="1000"
        />

    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:duration="1"


        />

</set>
```

My back animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="0"
        />

    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="-180"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:duration="1000"

        />

    <objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:duration="0"


        />

</set>
```

Comment: "I got bunch of errors". What errors?

Comment: applicationContext, unresolved reference and tvstartkaart.cameraDistance = 8000 * scale the * is Unreachable Code.